# Unordered.map insert issue with pair keys

Tags: c++, c++11, insert, iterator, unordered-map

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<Gdiplus::Color, float>, std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen>> mymap;
input = std::make_pair(color, width);
```

When i try to do

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(color,width), pen);
```

I get 
    C2664: 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist> std::_Hash<_Traits>::insert&>(std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>,_Valty)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>'
1>

i tried doing

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(input,pen))
```

but that also gives me an error. i don't understand why since input is a pair of color and float

I'm adding the whole code because i'm still getting issues

```
std::unordered_map<std::pair<Gdiplus::Color, float>, std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen>> mymap;
std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> getPen(Gdiplus::Color const & color, float width )
{   
    std::pair<Gdiplus::Color,float> input;
    input = std::make_pair(color, width);
    std::unordered_map<std::pair<Gdiplus::Color, float>, std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen>>::const_iterator got = mymap.find (input);

        if ( got == mymap.end() )
        {
            auto pen = std::make_shared<Gdiplus::Pen> ();
            pen->SetColor(color);
            pen->SetWidth(width);
            //std::pair<Gdiplus::Color,float> input2;
            mymap.insert(std::make_pair(input, pen));
            return pen;             
        }       
        else
        {
            if (std::shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Pen> m_pen = got->second)
               return m_Pen;
        }

}
```

};

```
 error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'size_t'   with
       [
          _Ty1=Gdiplus::Color,
          _Ty2=float
      ]
```

Comment: what is `Gdiplus::Color`? Is it an enum? If not, there could be missing hash function. Does std::map work?

Answer (score 3):

Use `emplace(key, value)` or `insert(pair)`.

```
mymap.emplace(std::make_pair(color, width), pen);
mymap.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(color, width), pen));
```

`insert(it, pair)` takes an iterator as its first argument (as an hint for performance reasons), not a key.

Comment: I'm still getting error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'size_t'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=Gdiplus::Color,
1>              _Ty2=float
1>          ]

Comment: it doesn't say the line though which is weird...ill post the whole code

Comment: @MichaelAfonso : If you're using VC++ 2010 then `emplace` is not supported.